# how to read source code of django-rest-framework, or any other python library

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am learning django-rest-framework. trying to figure out what's the diffrent bettwen update and partial update in modelviewset,so I decided to read source code, but source code in github with a lot of inherit relationships are difficult to read.

I found a website http://ccbv.co.uk/ when I learning about django,that really helpful to read source code, and now I found http://www.cdrf.co/ although this website pretty much the same as first one, but seems got a issue,no `__init__`.

anyway, I am just wanna know how experienced programmer learning about new library. and read and understand those source code efficiently?

Comment: While this isn't quite a programming question, I would recommend you clone the source of the DRF and go through it in an advanced editor or IDE. VSCode allows you to peek and trail references, making it super easy to move through source in a clean manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read the source code you can always read it from GitHub But if you want to get the source code instantly while you are working you should use pycharm editor. In that if you click any method with ctrl button then it opens source code of that.

Comment: Almost all code editors have that feature. If you have Vim keybindings enabled in any editor, try `ctrl-]` (and `ctrl-t` to jump back), or try right-clicking and looking for a menu item like "Go to definition". If neither of those work, search online for your specific editor. It should be `F12` in vscode.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the flow of library source code, I learn to understand how it works first (like how to use it).

My first time learning Django is from this [website](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/)

then, I learning DRF from this [website](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).